# How to code a valid XML sitemap

Tags: xml, sitemap

what do I need to include in a valid xml sitemap? Is there standards that I need to follow if so what are they? What do I need to include in a sitemap? What xml code makes an xml sitemap?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [sitemaps.org](http://sitemaps.org/).

Answer (score 2):

The sitemap is made of two standards. One of them is based on urlset and the other standard is based on sitemapindex.
Sitemaps are made with these two methods. In other words, each sitemap must be tested by both methods.
You can learn about these two methods from this link.

https://sitemaps.org/protocol.html#validating

You can also validate the sitemap with this tool.

https://sitemap-checkers.com/

Comment: Plus the XML standard itself.